# check string but skip number inside brackets?

Tags: python

I am trying to check if a string equals another string besides the different number variations enclosed inside brackets within the sting. Can anyone help me?

```
#example name: "hername: [485]"

name = "myname"
random_name = #random string from a list
objectname = (str(random_name))+": [#any number]")

if objectname.startswith(str(name)):
    #do something
```

Comment: You have to use `re` (regular expression) to check your pattern.

Comment: Would splitting on the `:` and comparing the first word with `name` work here?

Comment: Easy to do `if obj.startsWith(nm): val = int( obj.split(': [')[1][:-1] )` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most rigorous test is to use a regular expression:

```
import re

if re.search(r'^{}: \[\d+\]$'.format(re.escape(name)), objectname):
```

This will match strings that are exactly equal to `name: [number]`, where `number` consists of 1 or more digits.

You can be less rigorous and just test for `name: [`, if your object names always follow that pattern and you can assume there is always a number after the bracket:

```
if objectname.startswith('{}: ['.format(name)):
```

or simpler yet, assume that all your names always end in `: [number]` and just test for the name before the colon:

```
if objectname.partition(':')[0] == name:
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> objectnames = 'hername: [485]', 'myname: [42]', 'myname: [81]'
>>> name = 'myname'
>>> for objectname in objectnames:
...     if re.search(r'^{}: \[\d+\]$'.format(re.escape(name)), objectname):
...         print objectname, 'matches'
... 
myname: [42] matches
myname: [81] matches
>>> for objectname in objectnames:
...     if objectname.startswith('{}: ['.format(name)):
...         print objectname, 'matches'
... 
myname: [42] matches
myname: [81] matches
>>> for objectname in objectnames:
...     if objectname.partition(':')[0] == name:
...         print objectname, 'matches'
... 
myname: [42] matches
myname: [81] matches
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Could I just ask one more question, how do I return the numbers inside the brackets as and int? I thought `\[(.*?)\]` would work?

Comment: @justachap: you can put parenthesis around the `\d+`. Store the returned match object and use `.group(1)` to retrieve the digits.

Comment: @justachap: `match = re.search(r'^{}: \[(\d+)\]$'.format(re.escape(name)), objectname)`, then `if match:` then `number = int(match.group(1))` will assign the number as an integer to `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create regular expression.

```
import re

name = "myname"
random_name = #random string from a list
objectname = (str(random_name))+": [#any number]")
prog = re.compile(name+':.\[\d+\]')
if prog.match(objectname):
    #do something
```

Comment: This doesn't actually test if `name` is used and matched.

Comment: The OP is testing if `objectname` has `myname` at the start, not `hername`.

Comment: Now you are just testing of `objectname` follows the *general* pattern, not if `myname` (from the `name` variable) is in there.

Comment: What if `name` is `foo.bar`? Your expression will match `foo.bar [123]`, `foo_bar yo brother! [123]` and `foonbarnbaz: [123]`, etc. You are not escaping the `name` and allowing too many other characters after it.